# SQL - How to write a query to retrieve names based on IDs where names and IDs are stored in different table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-entities

I am working on developing a web application using asp.net

I have three tables with the following fields:

1. UserDetails:

   ---

   UserID(pk) |  FirstName |  LastName
2. Projects:

   ---

   ProjectID | ProjectName | CreatedByID | BudgetOwnerID | SpocID | LastUserID | StatusID

   NOTE: All IDs refer to the userID and statusID in the above and below tables.

3.Statuses:

---

StatusID |  StatusDescription

4. ResourceAllocation (UPDATED):

   ---

   AllocationID | ProjectID | UserID (To whom the project is mapped).

I need to display the details of the projects in a gridview in this way:

ProjectID | Projectname | CreatedByName | BudgetOwnerName | SpocName  LastUserName | StatusDescription

I want to display corresponding names(FirstName+LastName) for their ID's in the gridview.

How do I write it using either SQL or linq to entities?. Please help.

UPDATED:2ND QUERY:
I want to display the same details of the selected resource based on the projects to which he is allocated to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN` for each of the columns that you need name or description for:

```
SELECT 
    proj.ProjectID, 
    proj.ProjectName, 
    created.FirstName + ' ' + created.LastName as CreatedByName, 
    budget.FirstName + ' ' + budget.LastName as BudgetOwnerName, 
    spoc.FirstName + ' ' + spoc.LastName as SpocName, 
    lastUsr.FirstName + ' ' + lastUsr.LastName as LastUserName, 
    status.StatusDescription
FROM projects proj
    INNER JOIN UserDetails created ON proj.CreatedByID = created.UserID
    INNER JOIN UserDetails budget ON proj.BudgetOwnerID = budget.UserID
    INNER JOIN UserDetails spoc ON proj.SpocID = spoc.UserID
    INNER JOIN UserDetails lastUsrON proj.LastUserID = lastUsr.UserID
    INNER JOIN Statuses status ON  proj.StatusID = status.StatusID
```

Above query assumes that all of your `ID` fields will always be filled with data. If any of them can be `NULL`, you should change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: I tried this query but it is showing blue marks at budgetownername and where clause(below) that "It contains unresolved reference to the object".     Here is the query:                                                                                            CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].GetNamesByID
 @UserID int
AS
 SELECT 
    proj.ProjectID, 
    proj.ProjectTitle, 
 proj.ProjectType, 
    created.FirstName + ' ' + created.LastName as CreatedByName, 
    bugdet.FirstName + ' ' + bugdet.LastName as BudgetOwnerName, 
 spoc.FirstName + ' ' + spoc.LastName as SpocName,

Comment: lastUsr.FirstName + ' ' + lastUsr.LastName as LastUserName, 
ODCManID.FirstName + ' ' + ODCManID.LastName as ODCManName,stat.StatusDescriptionFROM PROJECT proj INNER JOIN USER_DETAILS created ON proj.CreatedByID = created.UserID LEFT JOIN USER_DETAILS budget ON proj.BudgetOwnerID = budget.UserID LEFT JOIN USER_DETAILS spoc ON proj.SpocID = spoc.UserID LEFT JOIN USER_DETAILS lastUsr ON proj.LastUserID = lastUsr.UserID LEFT JOIN USER_DETAILS ODCManID ON proj.ODCManagerID = ODCManID.UserID
  LEFT JOIN MST_STATUS stat ON  proj.StatusID = stat.StatusID
WHERE USER_DETAILS.UserID = @UserID
RETURN 0

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo. In `SELECT` clause it was `bugdet`, when it should be `budget` - letters d and g where switched places. I updated the answer, it should be working now

Comment: yes thankyou..one more small clarification..i added a where clause "WHERE USER_DETAILS.UserID = @UserID" at the end . It is showing the same message. What can i do for that?

Comment: @tennisno1 You are using `USER_DETAILS` many times in the query, so you need to be more specific, e.g. use `created.UserID = @UserID` or `budget.UserID = @UserID` or any other of the joined aliases

Comment: @dotnetom I have another query..Can u plz look into the updated question